# Hey I am getting this error while using chalk in NPM module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, npm-package

```
const chalk = require("chalk");
              ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module P:\Back End Development\NPM_modules\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js from P:\Back End Development\NPM_modules\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of P:\Back End Development\NPM_modules\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js in P:\Back End Development\NPM_modules\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object. (P:\Back End Development\NPM_modules\index.js:1:15) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I am Expecting a Blue Color code "Hello world"

Answer (score 2):

as the error says, the `chalk` package cannot be included in a **CommonJS** file with the `require()` method, as it is an **ES Module**.

To import an ES Module, you need to change your `package.json` file by adding in it:

```
    "type": "module"
```

and after, you'll need to import all your packages using the `import` statement, as in the following example:

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
```

If, for some reason, you don't want to change your `package.json` or you have to import your packages with **CommonJS**, you can use this method to import chalk:

```
var chalk;
(async function () {
    chalk = await import("chalk");
})();
```

but you'll need to be sure that the chalk package won't be used before it's *totally* imported.